# Use VLookUp table to set variable to equal a value

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have created a table on a worksheet within my workbook titled `LookUpTable` where it has data that looks like this

[image: LookUpTable]

What I want to do is reference that table to set variables to equal the table cell values within my if statement. Here is a portion of my code.

```
 If sweeprate_value = 50 Then
    sweep_value = 49.8
    sweep_value_max = 50.2
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmin, sweep_value)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmax, sweep_value_max)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
ElseIf sweeprate_value = 100 Then
    sweep_value = 99.8
    sweep_value_max = 100.2
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmin, sweep_value)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmax, sweep_value_max)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
Else: sweeprate_value = 200
    sweep_value = 199.4
    sweep_value_max = 200.4
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmin, sweep_value)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmax, sweep_value_max)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
    Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
End If
```

Where I have the lines `sweep_value = 49.8 sweep_value_max = 50.2` currently when I debug they both equal 50 which is not what I would like. For this case since `sweeprate_value = 50` then `sweep_value should = 49.8` and `sweep_value_max should = 50.2` as shown in the VLookUp table. Then follow the same flow for the other values. I do not want the values to be hardcoded into the script but rather reference the table to which those values could be changed if needed.

Comment: How did you declare your variable `sweep_value` and `sweep_value_max`? What type are they? If they are `Integer` or `Long`, they of course show `50` as value because those types do only allow full numbers no decimals. You should use `Single` or `Double` depending on the precision you need. • What code have you tried to reference those values in the sheet?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ They are declared as longs yes. So I should change them to double?

Comment: If you want them not to be `50` if you set `sweep_value = 49.8` you need to change them to `Single` or `Double` yes.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Oh, I get Long and Double mixed up. Thank you. That works for hardcoding the values, but is there a way to do it so it used a VLookup table

Comment: Yes the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ So I would have to define the headers in the table and then say for example `min = "49.8` `data = Application.WorksheetFunction("LookUpTable").VLookup(min, Range("A1:C4"), 2, 0)`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Or if I keep it as it is using `sweep_value` as a double, is there a way to cut back on the repetitive lines to make the code structure more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you set the values hardcoded like this. Make sure you have an error on non supported sweep rates. Do not repeat code.

```
Dim sweeprate_value As Long
Dim sweep_value As Double
Dim sweep_value_max As Double

If sweeprate_value = 50 Then
    sweep_value = 49.8
    sweep_value_max = 50.2
ElseIf sweeprate_value = 100 Then
    sweep_value = 99.8
    sweep_value_max = 100.2
ElseIf sweeprate_value = 200 Then
    sweep_value = 199.4
    sweep_value_max = 200.4
Else
    MsgBox "A SweepRate Value of """ & sweeprate_value & """ is not supported.", vbCritical + vbOKonly
    Exit Sub
End If

Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmin, sweep_value)
Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmax, sweep_value_max)
Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
```

Or you use a lookup:

```
Dim sweeprate_value As Long
' don't know where your sweeprate_value comes from so you get it here

Dim LookUpTable As Worksheet
Set LookUpTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LookUpTable")

Dim FoundAt As Double  ' get the row number of the `sweeprate_value` in the  LookUpTable
FoundAt = 0  ' initialize (needed if this is used in a loop!)
On Error Resume Next  ' next line will error if that `sweeprate_value` is not in the LookUpTable. Catch that error and hide it.
FoundAt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sweeprate_value, LookUpTable.Range("A:A"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0  ' re-activate error reporting!

' if `sweeprate_value` is not in the LookUpTable stop
If FoundAt = 0 Then
    MsgBox "A SweepRate Value of """ & sweeprate_value & """ is not supported.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim sweep_value As Double
sweep_value = LookUpTable.Cells(FoundAt, "B").Value

Dim sweep_value_max As Double
sweep_value_max = LookUpTable.Cells(FoundAt, "C").Value

Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmin, sweep_value)
Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, specmax, sweep_value_max)
Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
Call updateSD(sysnum, sweeprate_rowindex_1, spectyp, sweeprate_value)
```

Comment: Hi PEH, I am trying to follow along with the answer you gave using a lookup, and I am struggling to understand how the table will match up the correct `spec min` and `spec max` that correspond with the value that `sweeprate_value` will be. Would you be able to explain how that will happen, and if there is a way to refer to `B` and `C` as variables since there is no guarantee that when running this code, the vlookup table will be in those columns.

Comment: @resu_student The `WorksheetFunction.Match` will look for the `sweeprate_value` in your `LookUpTable` and return the row number where it was found in `FoundAt`. Which you can then use to get the value from the other colums at the same row using `LookUpTable.Cells(FoundAt, "B").Value`. If you need a backup plan if the `sweeprate_value` does not exist in the `LookUpTable` then replace  `Exit Sub` with hardcoded fallback values for `sweep_value` and `sweep_value_max`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with `Find` in place of `Match`?